# Ckeditor.js:211 - Cannot set property "dir" of undefined ( issue occurs for only one user)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ckeditor4.x

For some reason this error is coming up but only on one persons machine and CKeditor will not load  Cannot set property of "dir" undefined - line 211 ckeditor.js, I have tested the same setup in my machine with no issues.

For the same url path it works for me, but it shows "Failed to load resources: net:: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED " for that particular user.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOwzA.png)