# CKEditor - Error Decoding Failed - Not loading editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, iis-express

I have been using CKEditor for a bit on an older project. I just loaded it up in Visual Studio and noticed there is an issue loading the scripts. It appears when it loads, I get a DECODED_FAILED error in the console. Screenshots below... any thoughts as to why this would be different? VS has the latest updates and this is an ASP.Net MVC project.

While it may not be this exact reason, the editor is failing to load and it appears its because its not loading these initial files properly. Is this some sort of web.config issue? Or maybe the latest version of Visual Studio's updates?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you find the solution this? We've also hit this issue. Might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096189/ckeditor-js211-cannot-set-property-dir-of-undefined-issue-occurs-for-only

Comment: I have not come up with anything yet for my dev Visual Studio environment unfortunately, but it does appear to be similar to that issue. I figured the 'dir' error was because its not loading ckeditor.js... let me know if you find anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly we have not found a full-proof answer, but disabling GZIP on the IIS server allowed us to proceed using the control in the mean-time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/

UPDATE:
In messing with this, I noticed that if you turn of Static Compression for the site (within IIS) it works again. I also noticed that if I call the editor from the CKEditor CDN, the script works as well.

So calling it from the CDN allows you to leave Static Compression on.

Side Note: Not sure why, but when calling the script locally it adds on a parameter to the config.js?t=EAPE, which appears to be processed as a text/html content type. Unfortunately this is a legacy system so I did not mess with it any further, I have left Static Compression off for now.